Algebra of regular functions

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic set. Prove that the algebra of regular functions on $X$ considered as a quasi-affine algebraic set is the same as the algebra of regular functions on $X$ considered as an affine algebraic set.

From Hartshorne, I know that for an affine variety $X$, the ring of regular functions $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is isomorphic to the coordinate ring of that variety $A(X)$. Also I know that they form a scheme. But I can't show how to show that the algebra of regular functions are quasi-affine algebraic set.
Any help will be appreciated!
